# How can I cross-compile C code for a Cyrix Cx486DX?

Tags: c, cross-compiling

The question says it all. I need to cross-compile for a Cyrix CPU. The system the compiler (doesn't have to be gcc) needs to run on is a 64bit Kubuntu, with an i5 processor. I couldn't find anything useful googling, except for a piece of information saying that "Cx486DX is software-compatible with i486". So I  ran

```
gcc -m32 -march=i486 helloworld.c -o helloworld486.bin
```

but executing helloworld486.bin on the Cyrix machine gives me a floating point exception. My knowledge about CPUs is rather limited and I'm out of ideas now, any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Might it be that the executable format is different, rather than the instruction set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you need more than just a compiler that generates instructions for the 486. The compiler libraries, as well as any libraries that are linked in statically should be suitable as well. The GCC version included in most current Linux distributions is able to generate 486-only object files (I *think*), but its libraries and stub objects (e.g. `crtbegin.o`) have been pre-generated for 686 CPUs.

There are two main alternatives here:

- Use a Linux build system that is compiled for 486 itself, either in a VM or in a `chroot` jail. Unfortunately getting a modern Linux distribution for the 486 is a bit of an issue - every single major distribution has moved on. Perhaps a (much) older Linux distribution would be of help?
- Create a full [cross-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) toolchain for the 486. You can then cross-compile separate versions of all needed libraries and have your build scripts use them. Quite honestly, ensuring that nothing from the (usually 686-based) build host slips through to the build result is not very easy. It oftens amounts to cross-compiling a whole Linux system from scratch, ala [CLFS](http://trac.cross-lfs.org/).

  An automated cross-compiler toolchain build script, such as [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) might be of help.

Could you add more details about your target system? Is it an embedded system or just an old PC? What OS is it using? Would it be possible to just run your compile in a VM with a version of the target OS?

Comment: The target system is an old PC running debian sarge. I have an image of that system as a virtual machine accessible from my Kubuntu. I didn't think of compiling there because I thought the fact Virtualbox is presenting its fake hardware to the guest OS would destroy any advantage that might bring. But I'll follow your suggestion, install gcc there and compile on that VM directly, see what happens.

Comment: @Jane333: KVM allows the user to select the emulated CPU model, although I suspect that it just alters the reported CPU ID and features, rather than failing on an unsupported instruction (I have not tested it, I'm afraid). Perhaps VB can do the same somehow?

Comment: I finally got my helloworld.c to compile successfully, using a vmware virtual machine. The virtual machine was created after gcc was installed on the original hardware. I can run this VM on my 64 bit Kubuntu and compile with the command
`gcc helloworld.c -o helloworld`
, no compiler flags needed. This probably tells us that if the correct gcc is installed and all the libraries are there, no CPU emulation is necessary (vmware, like virtualbox, cannot emulate different processor architectures). Thanks, thkala!

Comment: @Jane333: That's probably the cleanest approach. I definitely understand the need to use a faster machine - the Cx486DX was a rather slow CPU, even at the time it was released...